# How put ScrollComposite inside another ScrollComposite in SWT

Tags: swt

How put ScrollComposite inside another ScrollComposite in SWT.
I use two scrollcomposite. the first ScrollComposite contains more than one ScrollComposite. Each Child Composite of equal size. So if the child ScrollComposite  contains widget of length more than fixed size, then it scroll(Each child ScrollComposite scroll according to containing widgets) and the parent scrollcomposite is scroll of the child composite exceeds it's length.

//Here is my code

```
      final Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

                    container.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
                    container.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
 //First Scroll Composite
                    final ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(container, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);

                    scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
                    scrolledComposite.setExpandVertical(true);

                    cmpNotificationBody = new Composite(scrolledComposite, SWT.NONE);
                    cmpNotificationBody.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
 //Second Scroll Composite
        final ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite2 = new ScrolledComposite(cmpNotificationBody, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER);

                    scrolledComposite2.setExpandHorizontal(true);
                    scrolledComposite2.setExpandVertical(true);
     cmpNotificationBody2 = new Composite(scrolledComposite2, SWT.NONE);

    //do  child GUI
    //Make Scroll Composite Scrollable
    scrolledComposite2.setContent(cmpNotificationBody2);
            scrolledComposite2.setMinSize(
                    cmpNotificationBody2.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
            cmpNotificationBody2.layout();

    scrolledComposite.setContent(cmpNotificationBody);
          scrolledComposite.setMinSize(
                    cmpNotificationBody.computeSize(1,1);
            cmpNotificationBody.layout();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this

```
final Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
container.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
container.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH)); 

final ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(container, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
scrolledComposite.setExpandVertical(true);

cmpNotificationBody = new Composite(scrolledComposite, SWT.NONE);
cmpNotificationBody.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));
scrolledComposite.setContent(cmpNotificationBody); 

final Composite scrollParent = new Composite(cmpNotificationBody, SWT.NONE);
final GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false, 1, 1);
data.heightHint = 100;
scrollParent.setLayoutData(data);
scrollParent.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

final ScrolledComposite scrollCmp = new ScrolledComposite(scrollParent, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
scrollCmp.setExpandHorizontal(true);
scrollCmp.setExpandVertical(true);

final Composite cmpBody = new Composite(scrollCmp, SWT.NONE);
scrollCmp.setContent(cmpBody);

final FillLayout layout = new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL);
layout.spacing = 10;
cmpBody.setLayout(layout);
//make GUI 

scrollCmp.setContent(cmpBody);
scrollCmp.setMinSize(cmpBody.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
cmpBody.layout(); 
scrolledComposite.setContent(cmpNotificationBody);
scrolledComposite.setMinSize(cmpNotificationBody.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
cmpNotificationBody.layout();
```